# REST based MVC site and/or WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, model-view-controller, rest

I know there are actually a number of questions similar to this one, but I could not find one that exactly answers my question.

I am building a web application that will

- obviously display data to the users :)
- have a public API for authenticated users to use
- later be ported to mobile devices

So, I am stuck on the design. I am going to use asp.net MVC for the website, however I am not sure how to structure my architecture after that.

Should I:

- make the website RESTful and act as the API

  - in my initial review, the GET returns the full view rather than just the data, which to me seems like it kills the idea of the public API
  - also, should I really be performing business logic in my controller? To be able to scale, wouldn't it be better to have a separate business logic layer that is on another server, or would I just consider pushing my MVC site to another server and it will solve the same problem?  I am trying to create a [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) design, so it also seems better to abstract this to a separate service (which I could just call another class, but then I get back to the problem of scalability...)
- make the website not be RESTful and create a RESTful WCF service that the website will use
- make both the website and a WCF service that are restful, however this seems redundant

I am fairly new to REST, so the problem could possibly be a misunderstanding on my part. Hopefully, I am explaining this well, but if not, please let me know if you need anything clarified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a separate business logic layer and a (restful) WCF layer on top of that. This decouples your BLL from your client. You could even have different clients use the same API (not saying you should, or will, but it gives you the flexibility). Ideally your service layer should not return your domain entities, but Data Transfer Objects (which you could map with Automapper), though it depends on the scope and specs of your project.

Putting it on another server makes it a different tier, tier <> layer.

Comment: Yes, I planned on using DTO's and AutoMapper. So, you are saying, I should probably not worry about a REST site, but have it consume a RESTful service? (Option 2 essentially)

Comment: Exactly that, although service layer != BLL. Your service layer should take care of DTO <-> entity mapping. Your business logic works with entities and does not need knowledge of services or datatransfer.

Comment: Yes, I agree entirely. In fact, this is the architecture I was planning on going before getting turned on to just using my website as a RESTful service itself.

Comment: I gave you the answer because all of the answers are pretty similar and go with what I was thinking already and agree with. So, I just went with this because you were first

Answer (score 1):

Plain and simple.... **it would be easiest from a complexity standpoint to separate the website and your API**.  It's a bit *cleaner* IMO too.

However, here are some tips that you can do to make the process of handling both together a bit easier if you decide on going that route. (I'm currently doing this with a personal project I'm working on)

1. Keep your controller logic pretty bare. Judging on the fact that you want to make it SOLID you're probably already doing this.
2. Separate the model that is returned to the view from the actual model.  I like to create models specific to views and have a way of transforming the model into this view specific model.
3. Make sure you version everything.  You will probably want to allow and support old API requests coming in for quite some time.... especially on the phone.
4. Actually use REST to it's fullest and not just another name for HTTP.  Most implementations miss the fact that in any type of response the state should be transferred with it (missing the ST).  Allow self-discovery of actions both on the page and in the API responses. For instance, if you allow paging in a resource always specify in the api or the webpage.  There's [an entire wikipedia page on this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS). This immensely aids with the decoupling allowing you to sometimes automagically update clients with the latest version.

Now you're controller action will probably looking something like this pseudo-code

```
MyAction(param) {
    // Do something with param
    model = foo.baz(param)

    // return result
    if(isAPIRequest) {
       return WhateverResult(model)
    }
    return View(model.AsViewSpecificModel())
}
```

One thing I've been toying with myself is making my own type of `ActionResult` that handles the return logic, so that it is not duplicated throughout the project.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the same as @diggingforfire's response, except your point number 4. Are you saying that I should go more to my third option (both MVC and WCF as REST)? If so, could you elaborate on why this is not redundant?

Comment: I was referring to the fact that the API should be driven by "hypertext". I'll clean it up.

Comment: Thanks, that was already my understanding of REST, so I should be ok there :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use the REST service for your website, as it won't add any significant overhead (assuming they're on the same server) and will greatly simplify your codebase. Instead of having 2 APIs: one private (as a DLL reference) and one public, you can "eat your own dogfood". The only caution you'll need to exercise is making sure you don't bend the public API to suit your own needs, but instead having a separate private API if needed.

You can use RestSharp or EasyHttp for the REST calls inside the MVC site.

[ServiceStack](http://servicestack.net/) will probably make the API task easier, you can use your existing domain objects, and simply write a set of services that get/update/delete/create the objects without needing to write 2 actions for everything in MVC.

Comment: So, you suggest Option 2 also? That seems to be the general consensus.

Comment: @Justin definitely don't go the WCF route, from my experience.

Comment: Why not? It seems to have decent capabilities to be RESTful. If not WCF, what would you suggest? I am open to using other languages, but would prefer to keep things in the same technology stack.

Comment: @JustinPihony ServiceStack would be my preference, or even just an extra action for each controller to return JSON/XML. WCF adds a lot of complexity that isn't generally needed imo.